# Why is there "no analogue of $2i\pi$ in $\mathbf C_p$"?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, integration, homology-cohomology, p-adic-number-theory

In his paper *Fonctions L p-adiques*, Pierre Colmez says:

> Tate a montré qu'il n'existait pas dans $\mathbf C_p$ d'analogue $p$-adique de $2i \pi$ et donc par conséquent que les périodes $p$-adiques des variétés algébriques ne pouvaient pas vivre dans $\mathbf C_p$.
>
> *(Tate showed that there does not exist in $\mathbf C_p$ a $p$-adic analogue of $2i\pi$, and therefore that the $p$-adic periods of algebraic varieties cannot live in $\mathbf C_p$.)*

He further explains that this realization led Fontaine to construct his complicated 'rings of periods'. He gives, as reference for the quoted claim, Tate's paper *p-divisible groups*. However, nothing that I've read in Tate's paper seems to immediately justify this surprising claim. I've read a bit about Fontaine's rings and I have an idea of the role they play in studying $p$-adic representations, but I'm not quite sure how to formally express "that there does not exist in $\mathbf C_p$ a $p$-adic analogue of $2i\pi$".

My feeling is that he is thinking about periods on curves, where the formal residue theorem of Serre-Tate allows us to explicitly describe Riemann-Roch-Poincaré duality in terms of a formal integration pairing. Over $\mathbf C$, this pairing can be calculated analytically by Cauchy's Residue Theorem, but it requires "division by $2i \pi$"... and somehow, we can't mimick this inside $\mathbf C_p$? is this right? if so, why can't we mimick it?

I would welcome any clarification or explanation of this matter. Thanks!

**Edit**: [This user comment](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/there-is-no-p-adic-2-pi-i/#comment-4780) on the blog post linked to by [anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/anon), seems to suggest that my hunch is correct. So how can we justify this claim, and get a good feel for the necessity of Fontaine's rings? And, how is this related to Tate's paper?

Comment: Related blog post on SBS: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/there-is-no-p-adic-2-pi-i/. (My understanding of most of the content here is zero; the most I can do is quote Strassman's theorem or say that continuous periodic functions out of ${\Bbb C}_p$ are locally constant.)

Comment: Thanks @anon, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think Colmez is referring to the fact that $H^0\bigl(G_{\mathbb Q_p},\mathbb C_p(1)\bigr) = 0.$

Any such invariant would be be a $p$-adic period for 
the cyclotomic character; but as Tate showed, this space of invariants vanishes,
and so the $p$-adic cyclotomic character does not have a period in $\mathbb C_p$;
one has to go to $B_{\mathrm{dR}}$ to get a period (the famous element $t$
of Fontaine).

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for your answer! Would you mind elaborating on why such an invariant would be a $p$-adic period for the cyclotomic character? Regards,